# Naming private fields and conflicted member ordering with the Airbnb-Typescript-ESLint-Config

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, eslintrc, eslint-config-airbnb

I have added eslint with Prettier and the Airbnb-TypeScript-Styleguide to my Angular-project and it says you shouldn't have any dangling underscores. How am I meant to name my private fields that are accessed through getters and setters?

Example:

```
private _isEnabled: boolean = false;
public get isEnabled() {
    return this._isEnabled;
}
public set isEnabled(v:boolean) {
    this._isEnabled = v;
}
```

If I rename *_isEnabled* to *isEnabled* it is no longer distinguishable from the getter and setter name. If I use a slightly different name like *enabled* it is no longer 100% clear that *enabled* should be accessed through its getters and setters.

I'm also running into an issue if I have multiple properties with getters and setters. If I order them like this:

```
get isEnabled() {...}
set isEnabled(v) {...}
get isHidden() {...}
set isHidden(v) {...}
```

I get an error saying 'get IsHidden()' should be with the other get properties. However, if I order them like this:

```
get isEnabled() {...}
get isHidden() {...}
set isEnabled(v) {...}
set isHidden(v) {...}
```

I get an error saying that overloads should be adjacent (get isEnabled() should be next to set isEnabled(v))

My eslintrc.json looks like this:

```json
{
    "root": true,
    "ignorePatterns": [
        "app/**/*", // ignore nodeJs files
        "dist/**/*",
        "release/**/*"
    ],
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": ["*.ts"],
            "parserOptions": {
                "project": [
                    "./tsconfig.serve.json",
                    "./src/tsconfig.app.json",
                    "./src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                    "./e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
                ],
                "createDefaultProgram": true
            },
            "extends": [
                // Angular's recommended settings
                "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
                // AirBnB Styleguide rules
                "airbnb-typescript/base",
                // Settings for Prettier
                "plugin:prettier/recommended"
            ],
            "rules": {
                "prefer-arrow/prefer-arrow-functions": 0,
                "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": 0,
                "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
                    "error",
                    {
                        "type": "element",
                        "prefix": "app",
                        "style": "kebab-case"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        // Rules for the HTML of Angular components
        {
            "files": ["*.component.html"],
            "extends": ["plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"],
            "rules": {}
        },
        // Rules for the TypeScript of Angular components
        {
            "files": ["*.component.ts"],
            "extends": [
                "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat",
                "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat--formatting-add-on",
                "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is my configuration wrong?

I'm using the linter mostly for consistency throughout my code. Is it possible to set and enforce a rule on how private fields are to be named and how the getters and setters are to be ordered when there are multiple properties with a getter and setter?

Comment: Why you use setter and getter ? Why not only use public attributes ?

Comment: I only use setters and getters if some additional funtionality is required when getting or setting a variable

Answer (score 0):

First, I do not recommend to use setter and getter if there is no use of it. Over-designing is not good practice.

You can always rename the private attribute with `Field` prefix like this:

```
private isEnabledField: boolean = false;
public get isEnabled() {
    return this.isEnabledField;
}
public set isEnabled(newValue:boolean) {
    this.isEnabledField = newValue;
}
```

As for your linting error, it's difficult to say without the specific error. My guess is that the attribute should be before the setter and getter like this:

```
private isEnabledField
get isEnabled() {...}
set isEnabled(newValue) {...}

private isHiddenField
get isHidden() {...}
set isHidden(newValue) {...}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
I have managed to solve the ordering error using the @typescript-eslint/member-ordering-rule and placing getters and setters in an array like so: ["public-get", "public-set"]

I really like your idea of using 'Field' as suffix for backing fields. My ideal solution would be to only force the underscore on backing fields and on no other properties. However, I do not think this is possible, given the docs (https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/naming-convention/) and this issue: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/816

Comment: I don't think that clean code recommend to use underscore since it's 'typing' your variables or attributes. It's in the same category as if you use bFlag : boolean; the 'b' is not recommended. Feel free to accept my answer :D